# return Json.Stringfy result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables, stringify

I have this piece of code :

```
$.getJSON('http://myjsonurl', function(json){console.log(JSON.stringify(json.columns)); });
```

This returns in the console all I need from my json response. My aim is to get this value into a function so that I can call it in another place. (For example :

```
"columns" : getColumns();
```

So I am making a function like this :

```
function getColumns() {
    $.getJSON('http://myjsonurl', function(json){return JSON.stringify(json.columns); });
    }

console.log(getColumns()); // and then call the function in the console log expecting to see the same result as before.
```

But all I get is undefined. 
Why?

UPDATE:

This is how I achieved what I wanted. The following code will reinitiate a datatable based on a json response with data and columns (something not supported natively from datatables). The code will reload the table with new query parameters and includes the buttons plugin :

```
var theurl;
theurl = "http://myjson.json";


function updateQueryStringParameternondt(key, value) {
    var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable();
    var ajaxurl = theurl;   
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = ajaxurl.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (ajaxurl.match(re)) {
    console.log( ajaxurl.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2'));
    theurl = ajaxurl.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
    table.destroy();
    TableManageButtons.init();

  }
  else {
       console.log( ajaxurl + separator + key + "=" + value);
    theurl =  ajaxurl + separator + key + "=" + value ;
    table.destroy();
    TableManageButtons.init();
  }
}

TableManageButtons.init();

var handleDataTableButtons = function() {


        0 !== $("#datatable-buttons").length && 

    $.ajax( {
  url:theurl,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function ( json ) {

      $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({
        "data" : json.data,
        "columns": json.columns,    
            dom: "Bfrtip",
            buttons: [{
                extend: "copy",
                className: "btn-sm"
            }, {
                extend: "csv",
                className: "btn-sm"
            }, {
                extend: "excel",
                className: "btn-sm"
            }, {
                extend: "pdf",
                className: "btn-sm"
            }, {
                extend: "print",
                className: "btn-sm"
            }],
            responsive: !0
        });
         }
} );
    },
    TableManageButtons = function() {
        "use strict";
        return {
            init: function() {
                handleDataTableButtons();
            }
        };
    }();
```

Comment: function getColumns() {
    return $.getJSON('http://myjsonurl', function(json){return JSON.stringify(json.columns); });
    }

Comment: @Ioannis Kokkinis You should return the response of the handler as well as the Promise from $.getJSON method and handle it. I'll provide a plunk to explain myself.

Comment: The `getColumns("$('#datatable-buttons').DataTable().ajax.url").always(function (response) { thecolumns = response;});` line will run asynchronously, so the value of `thecolumns` variable won't be set. Asynchronous means that JavaScript will run all  code until end and then will run the asynchronous "marked" code, to roughly explain it. So try put all your datatables instantiation logic in the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@guest271314 answer is correct and should guide you to resolve the issues regarding returning undefined from `getColumns` method.

I just want to point out some key things here.

First investigate the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/o9r0jRx4r78O9QlxCQcZ?p=preview) I created a moment ago. As you can see all the juice here is to manipulate the Deferred object (See [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more). Rougly explaining, the Deferred object can register callbacks, and if you like multiple ones, chain them, and by invoking them can broadcast their state's as well as their responses. It is based to promises design, so such methods return a promise which can be resolved, synchronous or asynchronous (most of times promises are useful in asynchronous operations).

jQuery's asynchronous methods, like `$.ajax` return a promise. `$.getJSON` is no different, as it calls `$.ajax` in the end which, as mentioned returns a jQuery Deferred Promise.

For jQuery's `animation` method, see @guest271314 comment below.

More on promise [here](https://api.jquery.com/promise/).

*From documentation*:

> Return a Promise object to observe when all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have finished.

A `promise`, when handled is either **resolved** or **rejected**. `resolve` stands for success responses, as `reject` stands for failures.
From documentation we can see that there are methods of `Deferred` object to handle success, failure or both.

> **deferred.done()** Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is
>   resolved.
>
> **deferred.fail()** Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is rejected.
>
> **deferred.always()** Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is either resolved or rejected.

So, let's get back to the OP's question. As you can see now from the code:

```
function getColumns() {
    $.getJSON('http://myjsonurl', function(json){return JSON.stringify(json.columns); });
}
```

There is no way for you to know the `getColumns` state, because you do not return the `promise`. When using the `$.getJSON` handler you essentially handling the response there without emitting the promise object. The `getColumns` function of course returns `undefined` because there is not sign of `return` and by default you get that.

Regarding the `deferred.then()` method, with this you can handle a promise also, handling its state as well as its progress. In the example code in Plunker I've posted above I do not care about progress, just only the state, so in the first example the promise is handled with the `.then()` method, with the first function to be the success handler and the second function to be the fail handler. Returning the response from them essentially means the promise gets resolved. I return the promise itself as well.

In the commented out section you can see that you can return only the promise if you'd like and resolve the response in `always` method

Comment: When inside the datatables initiliazation I do  :

"columns": getColumns("myjson.json").always(function (response) { return response; }),

Still I don't get the response. This is probably because datatables is trying to initialise before the value is returned?

Comment: Please update your question, by adding the jQuery data tables initialization code as well.

Comment: I guess I need to add the promise result before the init of the datatables?

Comment: @gdyrrahitis [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) returns `jQuery()` object; to return jQuery promise can chain [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise)  to element or collection, or call `.promise()` on animated selector or object outside of function that call `.animate()`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @MiguelBolan , no value is returned from `getColmuns()`. `return` `$.getJSON()` from `getColumns()`; use [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then) to access value returned from an asynchronous function

```
function getColumns() {
  return $.getJSON("http://myjsonurl");
}

getColumns().then(function(json) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(json.columns))
}
// handle errors
, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
};
```

Comment: @IoannisKokkinis Note, `console.log(getColumns());` could be called before `$.getJSON()` completes at `js` at Question. Also, return value from `getColumns()` would be a jQuery promise object, not `json.columns` as `JSON` string. The jQuery promise value can be accessed at `$.getJSON()` complete callback or , as used at post, `.then()`; or  you could use `.always()` to access either `success` or`error` result from `$.getJSON()`

Answer (score 1):

Your `getColumns()` function needs to return the variable, at the moment it is only being returned to the function but not out. Try this: 
{

```
function getColumns() {
    var ret;
    $.getJSON('http://myjsonurl', function(json){
          ret = JSON.stringify(json.columns); 
          });
    return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Still getting undefined when I do console.log(getColumns());   Is it posible that the call to json takes time to come and does not catchup?

Comment: You can run it synchronously using `$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
});`, (add that line before executing $.getJSON) although it would be easier just to move the print statement into `function(json){...}` after assigning the value of ret.

Comment: Based off this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465446/getjson-each-returns-undefined It seems asynchronous would probably be the way to go, any luck?

Comment: $.getJSON is asynchronous, returning a Promise, meaning in JavaScript that this piece of code is queued, the execution will be continued until there is no line left. Then JavaScript will ask for this in the queue and handle it. So, this approach is wrong. Should and must handle the promise with Promise API methods.
Documentation on Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise