# Why is value undefined at .then() chained to Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Given

```js
function doStuff(n /* `n` is expected to be a positive number */) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(n * 10)
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    if (result > 100) {
      console.log(result + " is greater than 100")
    } else {
      console.log(result + " is not greater than 100");
    }
  })
}

doStuff(9)
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data) // `undefined`,  why?
})
```

Why is `data` `undefined` at `.then()` chained to `doStuff()` call?

Comment: This Question/Answer is intended to be [canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992). There have been several question where this specific pattern, that it, the omission of `return`ing a value from function call or `.then()` has been the issue, including [Run JavaScript promises in order. One after the other ends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44422851/2801559) `promise` tag efficianodos do chime in, or not, if so inclined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Promise returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31315450/6188402)

Comment: @washington guedes this is a canonical answer. Only flag as duplicate if you find a real good one. ( not sth like *try this* )

Comment: Related [return Json.Stringfy result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37085922/), [Why is my function returning undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40519579/), [Fetch API - returned variable undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44475873/), [$.getJSON return/scope issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43691132/), [How to return value from a Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45122086/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because no `Promise` or other value is `return`ed from `.then()` chained to `Promise` constructor.

Note that `.then()` returns a new `Promise` object.

The solution is to `return` a value or other function call which `return`s a value or `Promise` from `.then()`.

```js
function doStuff(n /* `n` is expected to be a positive number */) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(n * 10)
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    if (result > 100) {
      console.log(result + " is greater than 100")
    } else {
      console.log(result + " is not greater than 100");
    }
    // `return` `result` or other value here
    // to avoid `undefined` at chained `.then()`
    return result
  })
}

doStuff(9)
.then(function(data) {
  console.log("data is: " + data) // `data` is not `undefined`
});
```

Comment: @NiketPathak The bounty was only to bring attention to the Question, or particular code itself, which has appeared several times in different questions.   If a description of the expected result is better described at another Answer that Question will receive bounty points. Though the inquiry itself is for posterity, and reference; no other reason. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992

Answer (score 11):

The problem were facing:

```
return 
(new Promise(..)) //the promise we want to return
.then(()=>undefined) // the promise were actually returning, which resolves to undefined
```

As you may already noticed, then returns a new promise. This has a good reason, it makes promise chaining easy, e.g:

```
getUser()//an asynchronous action
 .then(user=>login(user))//then if we get the user,promise to log in
 .then(token=>console.log("logged in,token is "+token) //then if we logged in, log it
 .catch(error=>"login failed");//catch all errors from above
```

But this also creates the small trap, we are facing. The solution could be returning the *original promise* and not the *new promise* automatically returned by *.then()* as this is resolved to undefined as the function inside then is not explicitly returning something:

```
//what were doing:
Promise.resolve(n*10)//the original promise resolves to n*10
.then(a=>undefined)//the then gets n*10 passed as a, but returns undefined
.then(b=>console.log(b));//b will be undefined  :0 

//what we want:
var promise=Promise.resolve(n*10);
promise.then(a=>undefined);//a is n*10, this resolves to undefined
promise.then(b=>console.log(b));//but this still logs n*10, as its the original promise  :)
```

So as you can see, to return the original promise, we simply store it in a variable, then assign a .then handler to it, and have still a reference to the original promise which we can assign other handlers to ( or return ).

In action:

```
function doStuff(n /* `n` is expected to be a number */) {

    //create a new promise and store it

    var promise=new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
           resolve(n * 10)
        },1000);
    });

    //add a then handler to this promise  

    promise.then(result=>console.log(result + " is "+result<100?"not":""+" greater than 100"));

    //return the original one

    return promise;

}

doStuff(9).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data) //not undefined, as original promise
})
```

Answer (score 5):

The doStuff is returning the `Promise`. But, your last `then` function is not returning any values, hence `data` is coming as `undefined`.

In promises, value of arguments of the next `then` function is the returned value of the previous `then` function.

```js
function doStuff(n /* `n` is expected to be a positive number */) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(n * 10)
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    if (result > 100) {
      console.log(result + " is greater than 100")
    } else {
      console.log(result + " is not greater than 100");
    }
    return result;
  })
}

doStuff(9)
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data) // `90`
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the result from the .then() chained to the Promise. You need to add return result; to the .then()

Answer (score 1):

Because your data value is the return value of the last `.then()`, your last `.then()` doesn't have a valid return value.

So, you can add the return value in the last `.then()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You must return the result from the `.then()` chained to the Promise.
In your case just add

```
return result;
```

to the first `.then()`.