# How to return value from a Promise

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, promise, bookshelf.js

I have been struggling with Promises and would like to know how things work with Promises.
In my project, I am using Bookshelfjs ORM for fetching the data from Postgres.

Here is the code that I am working on right now. I get an array of device ids in this request and each device is running in one of the two modes.

```
router.post('/devices', function (req, res, next) {
var currentData = [];
var deviceIds = req.body.devices;
loadash.forEach(deviceIds, function (device) {
    var deviceid = device.deviceid;
    Device.forge()
        .where({deviceid: deviceid})
        .fetch({columns: ['id', 'mode']})
        .then(function (fetchedDevice) {
            if(fetchedDevice.get('mode') === 1) {
                Model_1.forge()
                    .where({device_id: fetchedDevice.get('id')})
                    .orderBy('epoch_time', 'DESC')
                    .fetch()
                    .then(function (modelOne) {

                        //first push
                        currentData.push(modelOne.toJSON()); 

                        //array with first push data                
                        console.log(currentData)                                    
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            }
            else if(fetchedDevice.get('mode') === 2) {
                Model_2.forge()
                    .where({device_id: fetchedDevice.get('id')})
                    .orderBy('epoch_time', 'DESC')
                    .fetch()
                    .then(function (modelTwo) {

                        //second push
                        currentData.push(modelTwo.toJSON());

                        //array not empty here(shows data from both push)                
                        console.log(currentData);                                   
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
   });
//This shows an empty array
console.log('Final: ' +currentData);                                                           
});
```

Now, I know this is happening because of async nature of Javascript. My question is

1. how can I display final array after all `push()` have been executed? I tried doing this using `Promise.all()` method but did not have any success.
2. is it possible to return `modelOne` or `modelTwo` out of every promise and then push to an array? How can I achieve this?

Comment: 1. You will need something like Promise.all(arrayOfThings.map(() => (//return a promise))).then((results//array of result) => (_.forEach(...))); 2. you can return an object from promise through resolve. you can return by resolve({modelOne: ... , modelTwo: ...}) and then use them in then function by then((result) => {  use it });

Comment: @TyanHauChiau as I said, I tried `Promise.all()` but I was getting value from only `Device.forge()` promise. Maybe I was doing it wrong or had placed it at a wrong location. Could you please explain me how can I achieve this correctly with `Promise.all()`?

Comment: Did your code look something like this: say you wrap all your async function for one device called deviceFunc() { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => (if (model1) resolve(model1) else resolve(model1))) }. and you want to get an array of all devices. you do Promise.all(devices.map((device, index) => (deciveFunc(device))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map()` and `Promise.all()`, `return` a value from function passed to `.then()`

```
var currentData = loadash.map(deviceIds, function (device) {
    var deviceid = device.deviceid;
    return Device.forge()
        .where({deviceid: deviceid})
        .fetch({columns: ['id', 'mode']})
        .then(function (fetchedDevice) {
            if(fetchedDevice.get('mode') === 1) {
                // return value from `.then()`
                return Model_1.forge()
                    .where({device_id: fetchedDevice.get('id')})
                    .orderBy('epoch_time', 'DESC')
                    .fetch()
                    .then(function (modelOne) {
                        // return value from `.then()`
                        return modelOne.toJSON(); 

                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            }
            else if(fetchedDevice.get('mode') === 2) {
                // return value from `.then()`
                return Model_2.forge()
                    .where({device_id: fetchedDevice.get('id')})
                    .orderBy('epoch_time', 'DESC')
                    .fetch()
                    .then(function (modelTwo) {
                        // return value from `.then()`
                        return modelTwo.toJSON();

                    })
            }
        })

   });

   var res = Promise.all(currentData);
   res
   .then(function(results) {console.log(results)})
   .catch(function (err) {
     console.log(err);
   });
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked as expected. So just to know that I understand this correctly - `return modelOne.toJSON()` returns value to outer `then()` and this outer `then()` function is returning that value to `map` function, right?

Comment: Yes. Does `.toJSON()` return a `Promise` or a value that is not a `Promise`?

Comment: I think it returns a Promise with model attributes values.

Comment: The `Promise` returned from `.then()` should result in the value of the `Promise` at chained `.then()` `Promise.resolve(1)
.then(res => Promise.resolve(2).then(data => data))
.then(res => console.log(res)) // 2`

Comment: Sorry, according to Bookshelf documentation `toJSON()` returns serialized model as a plain object

Comment: Then that object should be returned from `.then()`. Note that `.then()` creates a new `Promise` object

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid nesting `then`, and keep the promise chain flat. Furthermore, you can join the two model cases into one piece of code (DRY). Finally, use `map` instead of `forEach` so you return an array of promises, which you can then feed to `Promise.all`:

```
router.post('/devices', function (req, res, next) {
    var promises = loadash.map(req.body.devices, function (device) {
        return Device.forge()
            .where({deviceid: device.deviceid})
            .fetch({columns: ['id', 'mode']})
            .then(function (fetchedDevice) {
                var model = [Model_1, Model_2][fetchedDevice.get('mode')-1];
                if (model) {
                    return model.forge()
                        .where({device_id: fetchedDevice.get('id')})
                        .orderBy('epoch_time', 'DESC')
                        .fetch();
                }
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
       });
    Promise.all(promises).then(function (currentData) {
        currentData = currentData.filter(model => model) // exclude undefined
            .map(model => model.toJSON());
        console.log('Final: ' +currentData); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Should `.catch()` be chained to `Promise.all()`?

Comment: It could be there or on the individual promises. In the second case, you would still get a result based on the other promises. Depends on what OP expects.