# Accessing data returned from another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, return

I am trying to get the promise returned from another function. Here is my code:

```
function getData(){
var result = [];
return new Promise(function(resolve){
var query = firebase.database().ref('groups');
query.once('value').then(data => {
    data.forEach(snapshot => {

        var gdata = snapshot.val();
        var grp = snapshot.key;
        result.push(grp);
    });
});
resolve(result);
});
}
```

I managed to print out the data for 'grp' variable from the function above. In my second fuction where I tried to access the data returned from promise:

However, from the second function, when I tried to print out in the .then(), nothing is actually printed out. Why is it so?

Thanks!

Comment: `result` is still empty when you call `resolve`.

Comment: So I should add another promise in that function?

Comment: You should use the `Promise.all(<Array>)` method to join multiple async functions.

Comment: I only have one async function which is the getData(). How can I implement it in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad news: If you need to use a `.then()` function to get the value you want (as with your firebase method) then you *have* to return a promise from your function. This is the case even for your inner function.

The good news is that `.then()` can be used to "convert" the return value of a function; and will even unravel returned promises for you (if, say, you decide you need to perform a second database call before you have your answer)

```
function getData(){
    var query = firebase.database().ref('groups');
    return query.once('value').then(data => {
        var result = [];
        data.forEach(snapshot => {

            var gdata = snapshot.val();
            var grp = snapshot.key;
            result.push(grp);
        });
        return result;
    });
    resolve(result);
}
```

Take note how I `return result` inside of the `.then()` function. Since I'm returning the result of `.then()`, this will then evaluate to a promise that, rather than purely returning `data`, will return `result`.

I'm less certain what you're doing with the second block. You shouldn't need the `Promise.all` or `map` around getData unless you actually intend to call it multiple times; and given that your list is empty, it seems like it's not called at all.

DISCLAIMER: I know the promises concept well, but not firebase. If firebase has unique aspects to it that change how this should work, I may be wrong.

Comment: I am trying to access whatever is returned from the getData() in the second block. How can I access the returned value in this case?

Comment: Should be just `getData().then(list => { ...`. Promises have complicated constructors, but anytime you're writing code around the ones being returned to you, even when making new ones, it can often be pretty short.

Comment: Hey sorry but just a quick check with you, let's say when I try to access the data returned in .then(), for each of them, I am passing as parameter to another function. For example, for each groups, I am passing the group as parameter to getMember(group). Then inside getMember(), I am performing the same thing to fetch data and return to plotData(). However, with the nested .then(), it is broken now.

Comment: @guest176969 That does sound more complicated and maybe expands past your question. However, it also sounds a bit like that could make use of that "Unraveled promises" idea I mentioned in my answer. `plotData` would, again, *have* to return a promise. If you return one call to `getMember()` inside `then`, the result will be `getMember`'s result (not just the promise made by `getMember`). Then you would have to expand that to use Promise.all and return all getMember calls. I'd encourage you to experiment to get a better idea of it. The resulting code should not be *very* long.

Answer (score 1):

First, firebase already returns a Promise, so there's no need to create a new one. You should put the data into result and return the promise directly.

```
function getData() {
    var query = firebase.database().ref('groups');
    return query.once('value').then(data => {
        let res = [];
        data.forEach(snapshot => {
            var gdata = snapshot.val();
            var grp = snapshot.key;
            res.push(grp);
        });
        return res;
    });
}
```

You can then simply chain that

```
function plotData() {
    return getData().then(data => {
        data.forEach(console.log);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am getting data.map is not a function error message

Comment: I don't know what data is. If it's an array, you can map it. If it's something else, post it. @guest176969

Comment: @baao It's a Firebase thing with only a `forEach` method that synchronously iterates it.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for clarification @Bergi

Comment: I had made [just the same mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704116/1048572) a few days ago :-)

Comment: :D @Bergi . I've edited the answer. Strange that they return a non standard object...

Answer (score 0):

You resolve the promise too early. But don't create new promises if you don't need to:

```
function getData(){
  var result = [];
  var query = firebase.database().ref('groups');
  return query.once('value').then(data => {
    return data.map(snapshot => snapshot.key);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

list.map() does not resolve, it is not a promise... Promise.all needs to receive a promise.

You probably wanted to invoke **getData()** there.