# Array from outer scope wrongly reported as empty when used in nested Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to collect data asynchronously using jQuery and Promise. Here's a brief idea of my code:

```js
(function () {
    let promises = [], results = [];
    const urls = ["https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/rails/rails/MIT-LICENSE"];
    for (let url of urls) {
        let p = $.get(url).then(
            // The actual job is to parse the response and make new requests
            // but for simplicity I'll just make the same request again here
            () => promises.push(
                $.get(url).then(
                    data => results.push(data))));
        promises.push(p);
    }
    console.log("Start");
    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
        console.log("Done");
        console.log(results);
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The strange thing is, I can see a noticeable delay before the `console.log` runs, but an empty array appears in my console. However, if I immediately enter `results`, I can see everything expected there. I see no error, either.

I believe it has something to do with me nesting promises in promises, but I have no idea how to hunt the bug down.

Comment: Mmh, it looks like it should work, but there is no reason to do it in such a strange way. Just do `promises.push($.get(url))` and `Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) { console.log(results); });`

Comment: @Pointy It's probably not that way in the real code, or there would be console errors.

Comment: Can you post the actual code instead of a "brief idea"? The problem may be in something you left out because you didn't think it was important.

Comment: Sorry all, I realized that this is not reproducing the error. I'm working on another MCVE.

Comment: Now the code is making *two* HTTP requests. I think you might make more progress if you'd trace what's going on (`console.log()`) yourself.

Comment: @Pointy But the second (inner) promise is inserted correctly into `promises`, right?

Comment: `.then(results.push)` should be `.then(results.push.bind(results))`

Comment: Well surely you don't really want to make each HTTP request twice, right?

Comment: @Barmar I'm using `results.push` as a shorthand for `data => results.push(data)`.

Comment: @Pointy Making two requests isn't the point here, nesting asynchronous requests (nesting Promises) is.

Comment: When you call `Promise.all()` at the end, the `promises` array only contains the outer promises, not the inner promises, because they're added asynchronously.

Comment: @iBug I know what you're trying to do with that, but it doesn't work as you've written it.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704116/1048572) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37801654/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

This is how promises are handled using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Push the promise into an array. Than resolve that array of promises, which will give the array of values.

```
var promises = [];
for (let url of urls) {
    // Save promise in p
    let p = $.get(url)
    // push promise p in promises array
    promises.push(p);
}
// resolve all promises
Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

The original code does not work because for each url, the value stored in p is a promise that will resolve to undefined as then is not returning anything.

```
(function () {
let promises = [], results = [];
const urls = ["https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/rails/rails/MIT-LICENSE"];
for (let url of urls) {
    let p = $.get(url).then(d => {
    results.push(d);
    // return the value
    return d;
    });
    promises.push(p);
}
console.log("Start");
console.log(promises);
Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
    console.log("Done");
    console.log(results);
});
})();
```

This will work.

Comment: `url in urls` should be `url of urls`, or you need to use `$.get(urls[url])`

Comment: While this might be a simpler way to write it, it doesn't explain why the original code doesn't work. They should be equivalent.

Comment: @Barmar Explained why the original code doesn't work