# Break promise map if throw error inside the loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js, hapi.js

I'm using Hapi Js and Sequelize to do something about my API and in this case I need to check everything first before go the next step.

This is my code

```
return promise.map(array, function (values) {
    models.Goods.find({
        where: {
            id: values.id
        }
    }).then(function (res) {
        if (!res || res.length === 0) {
            throw new Error("Item not found");
        }
    });

}).then(function (res) {
    //do something after check
    //next step
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

I need to check if the id is in my database or not before go the next step but in this code if there is any error the `throw new Error("Item not found");` never go to the `catch function` so I try to do something to get the error function. I changed the code inside the `promise.map`, I put catch function in `models.Goods` and `console.log` the error, the error shows up but the `promise.map` still running and go to the `//next step` section and not stop.

Please help me how to break the `promise.map` if there is an error in `models.Goods`

Thank you

Comment: Forgot to return models?

Comment: See [Why is value undefined at .then() chained to Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439596/why-is-value-undefined-at-then-chained-to-promise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only have forgotten to return the models, this

```
return promise.map(array, function (values) {
  models.Goods.find({
    where: {
```

should be:

```
return promise.map(array, function (values) {
  return models.Goods.find({
    where: {
```

you could omit the `return` key word if using arrow [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
Here is an example, I also put in some [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
return promise.map(array, ({id}) => 
    models.Goods.find({
        where: {id}
    }).then(res => {
        if (!res || res.length === 0) {
            throw new Error("Item not found");
        }
    }) // can't have ; here now
).then(res => {
    // do something after check
    // next step
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user is not found the query itself was successful, so the success callback is triggered. But since nothing matched your query, null is returned.  Which is why its not triggering an error in the first place.  As for the second part.

You cannot catch an error thrown in an asynchronous callback function using promises, since its context will be lost.

Using promises, the correct solution will be to reject the wrapping promise.

```
Promise.reject(new Error('fail')).then(function(error) {
  // not called
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error); // Stacktrace
});
```