# Promise handling - update db entry if exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I am stuck with new challenge on Promises.

Goal: Update the DB entry only if P_KEY exists.

current db is exposed through module and module has get and put method for db. Both returning Promise.

Approach:

1. API calls for update method handler on node js with ID and Set of values (json)
2. In handler for post method call to `get` method of db module check if value on promise success is empty or not if yes return false else true.
3. If true; data exists  call to `put` method of db module.

but somehow data it always returns false.  even if db entry has been made through db api.

```
/** Function to check if p_key exist*/
function checkIfPKExists(idVal){
  pkdb.get(idVal).then(function(value){
    if(value){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  function(err){
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  })
}

/** UPDATE METHOD **/
var ch = checkIfPKExists("p_k"+req.body.id);
if(!ch){
  res.send("pk does not exist oo " + req.body.id);
} else {
  var pk_promise = pkdb.put("p_k"+req.body.id, req.body.pk);
  pk_promise.then(
    function(){
      res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body.pk) + "Updated Successfully");
    },
    function(err){
      res.send("Error occurred : " + err);
    }
  )
}
```

My understanding is `ch` value is set from `checkPK` function and since thats a promise it just goes ahead and processes `if` loop which by default stands `true` and done irrespective whether element is there or not same result. Not found.

What can I do to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that no value is `return`ed from `checkIfPKExists()` function call, see [Why is value undefined at .then() chained to Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439596/why-is-value-undefined-at-then-chained-to-promise/44439597?s=4|0.4712#44439597). Use `.then()` and `.catch()` to get the `Promise` value returned from the function

```
function checkIfPKExists(idVal) {
  // `return` the `Promise` here
  return pkdb.get(idVal).then(function(value) {
    if (value) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  })
}

/** UPDATE METHOD **/
var ch = checkIfPKExists("p_k" + req.body.id);

ch.then(function(bool) {
// if `true` do stuff
if (bool) {
  var pk_promise = pkdb.put("p_k" + req.body.id, req.body.pk)

  return pk_promise.then(function() {
    return res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body.pk) + "Updated Successfully");
  }, function(err) {
    return res.send("Error occurred : " + err);
  })
} else {
  // do other stuff
  return res.send("pk does not exist oo " + req.body.id);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  // handle error
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped me understand promise handling better. Nice code flow as well.

Answer (score 0):

**checkIfPKExists()** is an asynchronous function, if you want to use ch you would have to use a **.then()** to get it in a function and then use the value.

```
function checkIfPKExists(idVal)
{
    return pkdb.get(idVal).then(function(value)
    {
        if(value)
        {
            return true;}
        else
        {   
            return false;
        }           
    }, function(err)
    {   console.log(err);
            return false;
    })  
}

 /** UPDATE METHOD **/
 checkIfPKExists("p_k"+req.body.id).then(function(ch){
    if(!ch)
    {
        res.send("pk does not exist oo " + req.body.id);
    }
    else
    {
        return pkdb.put("p_k"+req.body.id, req.body.pk).then(
            function()
            {

                res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body.pk) + "Updated Successfully");

            },
            function(err)
            {

                res.send("Error occurred : " + err);
            })
}})
```

Comment: Note, no value is returned from `checkIfPKExists()` function call at code at Answer

Comment: @marvel308  It answers my question. I upvoted the answer but not reflecting since I'm <15 on rep. I appreciate your time and help. Thank you!