# Jest unit testing a function that calls a function that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, jestjs

If I have code something like this:

```
import externalThing from 'externalThing'
import anotherThing from 'anotherThing'

function functionIWantToTest()
{    
    externalThing.doSomething()
    .then(data=>{
        anotherThing.do(data.Id)
    })
}
```

What is the best practice way to unit test this?

Ideally the test would be something like this:

```
import externalThing from 'externalThing'
import anotherThing from 'anotherThing'

jest.mock('externalThing',()=>jest.fn())
jest.mock('anotherThing',()=>jest.fn())

describe('when calling functionIWantToTest',()=>{

    beforeEach(()=>{     
       anotherThing.do=jest.fn()
       //mock external thing somehow so that it still the 'then' code

       functionIWantToTest()
    })

    it('anotherThing should be called',()=>{
        expect(anotherThing.do).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1)
    });
});
```

But when I try I just end up building a chain of mocked functions with jest.fn() and no code actually gets executed.

Comment: What is expected result of `functionIWantToTest()` call?

Comment: Hey @guest271314 its in the test :), for `anotherThing.do` to have been called with a param.

Comment: Have not tried `jest`. What does `jest.fn()` return? Are there two different assignments of values to `anotherThing.do`? Note that no values are actually returned from `functionIWantToTest()` call

Comment: `jest.fn()` returns a mocked function, you can provide mock implementation by doing `jest.fn(()=>{...} )`. Yeah its a void function, I am expecting it do call something else(there is more logic in the real code)

Comment: Ok. Though still no value is returned from `functionIWantToTest()` call. Why do you `anotherThing.do=jest.fn()` if `anotherThing` is a function that is already defined at `import anotherThing from 'anotherThing'`?

Comment: Because its a unit test, I am mocking everything that is not part of the current unit?

Comment: Yes, though your unit tests do not return any values. Again, am not familiar with `jest`. Would expect a function call which is being tested to return a value. Is a value not expected to be returned from either function?

Comment: Does it need too? I am expecting with `.toHaveBeenCalledWith`

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting. Should `jest.fn()` be `jest.fn` to reference the function? Are you just trying to determine if `1` is the parameter passed to `anotherThing.do()` call?

Comment: I want to test, when I call `functionIWantToTest`, subsequently `do(someThingFromAsyncCall)` happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not tried `jest`. You can use `console.assert()` to test the function calls and `Promise` values returned. Note, no value is actually returned from either of the function calls, if that matter to the expected result, see [Why is value undefined at .then() chained to Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439596/why-is-value-undefined-at-then-chained-to-promise).

```js
function functionIWantToTest() {
  return Promise.resolve({
      Id: 1
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.assert(data.Id === 1, data, [`${data.Id} is not equal to 1`]);
      console.assert(data.Id !== 1, data, [`${data.Id} is equal to 1`]);
    })
}

functionIWantToTest()
```