# async/await and templating with pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm new to using async/await in nodejs and am confused about how to return data that I want for use in a view. Here is my code. below is the homeController, which is used like so: 
`app.get("/", homeController.index);`

I tried making the `index` method async, but i still can't console out the news data. what is the right way to resolve the article information so it's available for consumption in the view in `home`?

```
async function getNewsData() {
  const pool = await connection;
  const result = await pool.request()
    .input("StoryID", sql.Int, 154147)
    .execute("News.uspStoryByIdGet");
  console.log(result, "the result from the stored procedure");
  return result;
}

const article = getNewsData().
catch((e) => {
  console.log("the error", e);
});


export let index = async(req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const article = await getNewsData();
  console.log(article, "yoo");
  res.render("home", {
    article,
    title: "Home",
  });
};
```

Comment: so, what does `console.log(article, "yoo");` result in?

Comment: it isn't even being consoled

Comment: oh I see now ... `getNewsData` doesn't return anything, and it needs to return a Promise if you want to await on it (marking it async forces the return value to be a Promise, however, as it is it returns an immediately resolved `undefined`

Comment: does `pool.request().input(...).execute(...)` return a Promise?

Comment: it does now, but it's still nto working, see my edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for what I can see you should probably not be `await`ing for `connection` in your `getNewsData` unless for some reason `connection` is a promise that is was or is waiting to be resolved.

you should also be returning `result` on `getNewsData` function.

If that is not what is causing the problems there here are some clarifications about `async/await`

1 - Calling an async function behaves similar to calling a function that returns a `Promise`
2 - when you use `await` its behaves as if you wait for a promise to be resolved and extract the result from it, which you would have in your scope instead of having passed to a callback function in the `then` or `catch` methods.

feel free to reply to this answer if still in doubt.

Comment: check this out @devdropper87, make any modifications here and send back another pen so we are in the same page
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PJELxX?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

No value is `return`ed from`getNewsData()` function call, see [Why is value undefined at .then() chained to Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439596/why-is-value-undefined-at-then-chained-to-promise) You can  `return row` from `getNewsData()` if expected result of `getNewsData()` call is `rows` array.