# mapping a Promise function to an array does not persist results

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I have an object with two arrays as properties:

I want to populate the arrays by running promises in series.
I fetch the result of the promises, and map a function to decorate all the items in my arrays.

While one array get populated and persist, the other get populated only while in the `map` function, but at the end the array is returned still empty.

Can you help to understand why?

I check the Promise is actually returned, and indeed in one case it works, not in the other.

this is my pseudo-code:

```
function formatMyObject( arrayOfIds ) {

// initialize the objet
var myObj = {
   decorators = [],
   nodes = []
   ...
}

// I map the Promise reconciliate() and push the results in the array:

return reconciliateNode(arrayOfIds)
       .then( data => { 
             data.map( node => {
                //  I fetch results, and   myObj.nodes

             myObj.nodes.push( { ...   })
            })

       })

     return myObj
    })
   .then( myObj => {

      // myObj.nodes is now a NON empty array

      // I want to the same with myObj.decorators:

      var data = myObj.nodes

      // I think I am doing just as above:

      data.map( node => 
          decorateNode(node.source)
            .then( decoration => {

              decoration = decoration[node.source]

              myObj['decorators'].push( {
                    ... 
              } )

              // I check: the array is NOT empty and getting populated:
              console.log('myObj.decorators', myObj)
              debugger
          })
    )

    // instead now, just after the map() function, myObj.decorators is EMPTY!
    console.log('myObj.decorators', myObj);
    debugger


    return myObj
)

... // other stuff
}
```

Comment: Because the remaining portion of `formatMyObject()` runs before the promise has completed.

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation and the unbalanced braces in your code? It is not entirely clear how you really have it.

Comment: See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/); [Why is value undefined at .then() chained to Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439596/). _"I want to populate the arrays by running promises in series."_ What do you mean by _"in series"_?

Comment: _"if you think I need to amend the title to make it clearer or more exhaustive, please let me understand better your suggestion."_ Yes, can you include what you mean by _"in series"_ in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the second case the `map` callback returns a promise, that case is quite different from the first case.

In the second case, you would need to await all those promises, for which you can use `Promise.all`.

The code for the second part could look like this:

```
.then( myObj => {
    return Promise.all(myObj.nodes.map(node => decorateNode(node.source)));
}).then(decorations => {
    myObj.decorators = decorations.map(decoration => {
        decoration = decoration[node.source];
        return ({
            ... 
        });
    })
    console.log('myObj.decorators', myObj);
    return myObj;
})
```

Comment: Is _"in series"_ at the question omitted from being addressed at the answer for lack of clarity as to what that term means at the actual question?

Comment: @guest271314, I took this to refer to the two phases the OP has, which indeed are chained -- no problem with that. I understood the question not to be about that aspect, but about: *"at the end the array is returned still empty. ...why?"* -- also reflected in the title *"...does not persist"*

Comment: Interesting perspective that had not considered.

Comment: @trincot I marked as correct because it works and i understand I have to wait for all the promises, but not clear that, when I ` // I check: the array is NOT empty and getting populated: console.log('myObj.decorators', myObj)`while being in the map function, I see that `myObj.decorators` is not empty, while outside of the `map`function it is. Why the map object is returned to the next `then()`and does not keep reference to the array property that is being populated ? - hope I was clear to let you understand my question.

Comment: @guest271314 if you think I need to amend the title to make it clearer or more exhaustive, please let me understand better your suggestion.