# return error after convert file Input to Base 64

Tags: javascript, angular

according to [How to convert the file to base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript) I found a way to convert the image to base64 in javascript based following :

```
//My Converter Function
        function getBase64(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
            console.log("befor");
            console.log(reader.result);
            console.log("after");
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        };
    }
```

and I use it by:

```
getBase64(file).then(
    data => (Image64bit = data)
```

It seems I got 64bit string But I return this error every time:
(notice that without "then" it wont return anything)

> zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read property 'then' of
>   undefined**
>       at UploadFileAndGetUrl (doctors.js:14949)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (doctors.js:14703)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (zone.js:496)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1566)
>
> befor
>
> doctors.js:14992
>   data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAH0CAMAAADynrlKAAACBFBMVEUAzG9U1pBn2Zskz3vV8+H////g9umH4K71/Pjr+fHJ8Nm97dE/04aj5sCW47d43aSw6sg1143j+e801owDzXHS9ubQ9uRm4.....
>   doctors.js:14993
>
> after

How Could I resolve this error?

Comment: Your function doesn't return a promise so you cannot call `.then()` on it,

Answer (score 1):

> zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at

Function`getBase64` doesn't return a `Promise`.

You need to correct `getBase64` in the way that it returns a `Promise` and been resolved inside of `reader.onload` with the value of `reader.result`:

```
function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
      console.log("befor");
      console.log(reader.result);
      console.log("after");
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
      reject(error);
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No value is `return`ed from the function, see [Why is value undefined at .then() chained to Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439596/why-is-value-undefined-at-then-chained-to-promise)?.

`FileReader` `load` event is asynchronous, a value cannot be `return`ed from the event handler. You can use `Promise` or `async/await` to resolve a `Promise` where the value can be accessed at chained `.then()`, and `.catch()` to an handle error.

```
  function getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = function () {
        console.log(reader.result);
        resolve(result);
      };
      reader.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
        reject(error);
      };
    });
  }

  getBase64(file).then(
    data => {  
      // do stuff with data
  })
  // handle error
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```