# Console log undefined after fetching api in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When fetching from an API (3rd party, I authenticate and get the data in my Laravel Controller) I get 'undefined' in the console. I want to store the data in a Vue component.

I tried a bunch of different things, including a get instead of fetch, but this also logged undefined. I did some research and read about arrow functions but I am not using an arrow function.

```
data() {
    return {
        tickets: [],
    };
},

created() {
    this.fetchTickets();
},

methods: {
    fetchTickets() {
        fetch('/api')
        .then(res => {
            this.tickets = res.json;
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.json);
        }) 
    }
}
```

So, what I want is the collection made out of the get request I send to a 3rd party API in PHP which is returned to the route /api, stored in my Vue component. Now it just logs undefined.

EDIT Backend request in PHP

```
 $response = $client->get('v1/tickets/search.json', [
        'query' => ['statuses[]' => 'active', 'assignedTo[]' => 314955, 
        'sortDir' => 'desc', 'sortBy' => 'updatedAt']
    ]);

    $json = (string)$response->getBody()->getContents();
    $decoded = json_decode($json, true);
    return collect($decoded);
```

Route:
     Route::get('/api', 'ApiController@getTickets',);

Comment: You forgot to return from your first then `return  res`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is value undefined at .then() chained to Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439596/why-is-value-undefined-at-then-chained-to-promise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` returns a promise containing the response `res`.
(This  is just an HTTP response, not the actual JSON.)

To extract the JSON body content from the response, we use the `json()` method

You can read more about [using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
fetchTickets() {
    fetch('/api')
    .then(res => res.json()) //returning a promise To extract the JSON body content from the response
    .then(resJson => {
        this.tickets = resJson
        console.log(resJson);
    }) 
}
```

Comment: The information I got from the API now is properly logged in the console! Thank you!

Comment: Oh I have one more question, how does resJson get defined? Does .then just pass on the contents of res => res.json()?

Answer (score 2):

Return your data before going in second promise.

```
fetchTickets() {
    fetch('/api')
    .then(res => {
        this.tickets = res.json;
        return res;
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.json);
    });
```

Comment: It still says undefined in console.log for some reason

Comment: @ScottvanDuin Explained the logic in answer. In first then you need to return res.json() then you will get json object in next then.

Answer (score 2):

add the return statement in the first promise

```
fetch('/api')
  .then(res => {
      return res.json();
   })
   .then(tickets => {
     // tickets is a local variable scoped only here
     console.log(tickets);
   })
```

Comment: Tickets isn't defined anywhere, this just errors: "app.js:1792 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: tickets is not defined
    at app.js:1792"

Comment: ticket is a local variable in the second promise scope, you shoudnt' make it globally available because you're relying on some async code to populate the value

Comment: But then how exactly would this be stored in the data() of the component? (I'm a noob to vue and javascript on this level)

Comment: what's the purpose of the data() method, can't you just pass tickets when you call data(tickets) ?

Comment: This way I can mount a prop that will be passed on to a different component, I will be using the data from the API more than once, so I dont want to be fetching individually in each component

Comment: ok then you can set the tickets globally or with maybe a better approach would be using an external state management library