# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: res.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I'm trying to fetch a list of departments from an url in a react native application

```
import React,{ useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, LogBox,View,Text } from 'react-native';




export default function App() {
var [department,setDepartment]=useState([])
const token = /* my token here */

  const getDepartments=()=>{  
    const url = /*my api's url here*/

      return fetch(url, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer" + token ,
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
      }
      })
          .then(response => response.json())
           .then(data=>console.log(data)) // returns the correct data
          .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }

   const getdepartment = async () => {
            await getDepartments().then((res) => //here lays the problem
              {res.map((p, key) => {
                department.push({
                  name: p.name,
                  id: p.id,
                });
              });
            });
          };

          useEffect(() => {

            getdepartment();

          }, []);

  return (
  <View>
  <Text>
             {department[0]}
                            </Text>

              </View>
  )
}
```

here res in the getdepartment() function is undefined despite the getDepartments() function returning correct data from the url

Comment: You don't need to use `await` if you're going to use `.then` Just use `const response = await getDepartments();` then do all the logic on the response variable, so `response.map ...`

Comment: Remove `.then(data=>console.log(data))` or change it to `.then(data=>{ console.log(data); return data; })`

Comment: @ponury-kostek I tried both .. still doesn't work

Comment: You sure `res` is an array? Map doesn't exist on objects

Comment: I think @skrrrt and @ponury's comment should help you figure what's wrong. First, check that the data is actually an array. Second, make sure to return the data in your promise by `.then(data=>{ console.log(data); return data; })` (note that the curly braces is necessary). By `console.log` but not return anything, you are not getting any value from that promise chain (thus the `undefined`)

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam but I made a return before the fetch

Comment: that `return` before the fetch is returning the promise chain. Inside the actual promise chain, you then did `.then(data => {return console.log(data)})`. Because `console.log` returns nothing, you effectively did `.then(data => undefined)`. Therefore, as the last `then` returns nothing, the entire promise chain will resolve to nothing.

Comment: my other apis worked without the need of the second return

Comment: It is actually not the second return. The [arrow function shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `() => something` (without curly braces) is actually shorthand for `() => {return something}`. Therefore, `.then(response => response.json())` is actually `then(response => {return response.json()}`. In each of the `then`, you need to return the data that the next `then` will access. Your "other apis" probably might have worked because they did not return `console.log` in the middle of the promise chain.

Comment: @coldprogrammmer I just found this post that may explain this better than I do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439596/why-is-value-undefined-at-then-chained-to-promise

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a value from getDepartments, just a simple console.log.

You can convert the function in async/await:

```
const getDepartments = async () => {  
    const url = /*my api's url here*/
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer" + token ,
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
      }
      })
      return await response.json();
      } catch(e){
        // error
      }
  }
```

or return a value from your function:

```
const getDepartments=()=>{  
    const url = /*my api's url here*/

      return fetch(url, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer" + token ,
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
      }
      })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning the result of the fetch then just return the result obtained from it, the issue is along with fetch, the response is also handled and the complete thing post to that is being returned which is not the result so you just need to skip this line            .then(data=>console.log(data))

```
const getDepartments=()=>{  
const url = /*my api's url here*/

  return fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer" + token ,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
  }
  }).then(response =>  response.json()).catch(error => 
     console.error(error))
   
  }
```

// Here after fetching the result you can map the data

```
  const getdepartment = async () => {
        await getDepartments().then((res) => 
          {res.map((p, key) => {
            department.push({
              name: p.name,
              id: p.id,
            });
          });
        });
      };
```