# Promise all with axios in react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, axios

I'm making a react-native weather forecast app. And I'm trying to get all the data using 2 promise all methods

This is the function I call in useEffect

```
async function getData(){
  try{

    Promise.all(_.map(savedPlaces, getCurrentWeather)).then((response) => {console.log("current", response.data)})
    Promise.all(_.map(savedPlaces, getDailyWeather)).then((response) => {console.log("daily", response.data)})

  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

The `savedPlaces` variable is an array with names of the cities I want to get the weather for

And this is one of the two fuctions i use to get the data

```
const getCurrentWeather = async (places) =>{

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/weather',
    params: {q: places.name, lang: 'null', units: 'metric', mode: JSON},
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com',
      'x-rapidapi-key': 'xxx'
    }
  };

  const request = await axios.request(options).then(response => {console.log(response.data)})

  return request

}
```

The other funtion is basicaly the same except little changes in `options`

And the issu is that I can see the data in print out in this code fragment

```
.then(response => {console.log(response.data)})
```

inside the `getCurrentWeather` functions but when I try to print them out in .then after Promise.all I get undefined, same with the other function.

```
current [undefined, undefined]
```

And I'm asking how to properly do it

Comment: Don't mix classic promises and async/await. Just use one or the other

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is value undefined at .then() chained to Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439596/why-is-value-undefined-at-then-chained-to-promise)

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
const request = await axios.request(options)
    .then(response => {console.log(response.data)})
```

The callback under `then` prints the data in the console, but has no return statement (returns undefined). Therefore this

```
return request
```

returns undefined wrapped in a promise.

Add `return response` (or `return response.data`) after the `console.log` and it should get better.