# Second useState doesn't update in promise chain

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, callback, react-native-reanimated

With React Native, this app needs to:

1. Move an object
2. Then update text (a number) on the screen
3. Then move another object
4. Then update the same text (another number) on the screen

**Problem: #4 does not update on the screen.**

This [GIT link](https://github.com/Micah81/Move2Cats/blob/main/App.js) shows the current code.

Google explains the issue: "The useState hook in React does not update twice in a promise chain. This is because React batches state updates, meaning that all state updates that occur within a single event loop cycle are grouped together and applied at the end of the cycle. This helps to improve performance by avoiding unnecessary re-renders."

So maybe this button should call two Promises one after the other, with each one chained to a useState update. The second promise animation could have a delay of the same duration as the first animation, to make them consecutive. I haven't plugged this in yet to try it, will do so soon.

The animating functions look like this:

```
  function updateNumCatsMoved(){
    let newNumCats = { ... numCatsMoved };
    newNumCats.value = newNumCats.value + 1;
    setNumCatsMoved(newNumCats);
    console.log("numCatsMoved:",numCatsMoved.value);
  };

  async function pressablePromise(){
    new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
      cat1X.value = withTiming(cat1XEnd, config);
      cat1Y.value = withTiming(cat1YEnd, config, () => {
        runOnJS(myResolve)(); 
      }); 
    })

    .then(function() {  return updateNumCatsMoved();})

    .then(
      function() { 
        cat2X.value = withTiming(cat2XEnd, config);
        cat2Y.value = withTiming(cat2YEnd, config, () => {
          return; 
        }); 
      }
    )
     // doesn't update on the screen 
    .then(function() {  return updateNumCatsMoved();})  
  }
```

Comment: If `updateNumCatsMoved()` returns a `Promise` you need to `return` that `Promise` from `then()`, see [Why is value undefined at .then() chained to Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439596/why-is-value-undefined-at-then-chained-to-promise).

Comment: @guest271314 thank you. sounds like I'll be making it a promise. and then it will update at the end for #2.

Comment: `then()` returns a new `Promise`. If you really want to return `1` you can do something like `.then(function(value) {  return updateNumCatsMoved();}).then(function() {return 1})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was achieved by passing a value to the useState function. The value is the amount to update with. In my real app, the update can be -1, 0, or +1. This problem led to me learning about promises and how React batches state updates.

A bit of an issue to deal with moving forward is that the useState starts with 0 for both updates. I think I can use a local variable to help with that.

And so it WAS doing both updates, but they each started at 0. So it only went from 0 to 1.

```
  function updateNumCatsMoved(n){
    let newNumCats = { ... numCatsMoved };
    newNumCats.value = newNumCats.value + n;
    setNumCatsMoved(newNumCats);
  };

  function pressablePromise(){
    new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
      cat1X.value = withTiming(cat1XEnd, config);
      cat1Y.value = withTiming(cat1YEnd, config, () => {
        runOnJS(myResolve)(); 
      }); 
    })

    .then(function() {  return updateNumCatsMoved(1);})

    .then(
      function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
          cat2X.value = withTiming(cat2XEnd, config);
          cat2Y.value = withTiming(cat2YEnd, config, () => {
            runOnJS(resolve)();
          }); 
        })
      }
    )
     
    .then(function() {  return updateNumCatsMoved(2);})  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

withTiming callback function seems to be an async function.

So you need to update

```
.then(
      function() { 
        cat2X.value = withTiming(cat2XEnd, config);
        cat2Y.value = withTiming(cat2YEnd, config, () => {
          return; 
        }); 
      }
    )
```

to

```
.then(
      function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
          cat2X.value = withTiming(cat2XEnd, config);
          cat2Y.value = withTiming(cat2YEnd, config, () => {
            resolve(); 
          }); 
        })
      }
    )
```

Comment: Thank you, I made this update but the result is the same. I think it's because React batches state updates; I added this info also to the question.